# Nested tables in email

Tags: html, email

So, I'm totally losing my mind with an email that I'm trying to format.

I think it has to do with a particular nested table.

The main table is 650px wide and the width of the nested table is set to 100%.

What's happening is that, as soon as I plug in the nested tables, the header and footer images are being reduced by 20px(10+10) on the right side(despite both images being 650 pixels wide).

When I modify the nested tables to make the cellspacing on both sides of the nested tables =0(originally 10px on both sides i.e. 20px in total), then the header and footer images line up correctly but, assuming the cellspacing is set to 10 px on each side of the nested table, then the header and footer images get reduced.

Why is the nested table cellspacing affecting my table header and footer images?

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>2020 Preferred Share Outlook with Fiera Capital</title>
<style type="text/css">
<!--
html, body {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: #444;
    font-size: 17px;
    line-height:30px;
    background-color: #FAFAFA;
}
img {
    border:none;    
}
sup, sub {
  vertical-align: baseline;
  position: relative;
  top: -0.4em;
}

.disclaimer {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: #666;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height:16px;
}
.title {
    color: #F60;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 25px;
}
.title2 {
    color: #F60;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 20px;
}

a:link {
    color: #F60;
}
a:visited {
    color: #F60;
}
a:hover {
    color: #F60;
}
a:active {
    color: #77881c;
}
.orange {
    color: #F60;
}
.disclaimer{
padding:15px;
    }
.table_data {
    font-size: 9px;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    border-color: #FDFDFD;
    line-height:12px;
}
.disclaimer1 {  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: #666;
    font-size: 11px;
    line-height:16px;
}
.details {
    font-size: 13px;
    line-height:20px;
}   
-->
</style>
</head>

<body style="margin: 0;">
<table width="101%" height="100%">
  <tr>
    <td><table width="650" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
      <tr> 
            <td width="650">
                <img src="https://www.horizonsetfs.com/horizons/media/emails/2020/202002_FieraWebinar/Email_Header.png" alt="2020 Preferred Share Outlook with Fiera Capital" style="border:none"/>
            </td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
          <td align="left" style="padding: 15px 20px 20px 20px;">
            <p class="title">Get the Latest Outlook from Fiera Capital on the Canadian Preferred Shares and Fixed Income Markets</p>
            <p>The Canadian preferred share market has bounced back from its lows in Q3 2019. But Fiera Capital believes there is still significant potential upside left in this asset class, since preferred shares offer higher relative yields compared to bonds, and should have less pressure from new issuances in 2020.</p>
            <p>Fiera Capital’s Nicolas Normandeau, lead portfolio manager for the <a href="http://www.horizonsetfs.com/hpr">Horizons Active Preferred Share ETF (HPR)</a> and the <a href="http://www.horizonsetfs.com/hfp">Horizons Floating Rate Preferred Share ETF (HFP)</a>, will outline his team’s outlook for Canadian preferred shares in 2020, and why he feels they remain a potentially attractive option for Canadian fixed income investors.</p>
            <p><a href="https://attendee.gotowebinar.com/register/6491065155959682573?" target="_blank"><img src="http://horizonsetfs.com/horizons/media/emails/common-images/register_en.png" alt="Register for the webinar Now" style="border:none"/></a></p>



            <table width="100%" cellspacing="10" cellpadding="10" border="0">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td width="50%" bgcolor="#EEEEEE"><br><span class="title"><strong>Advisors and Investors Bullish in New Decade<br>
                            <a href="https://www.horizonsetfs.com/sentimentsurvey" target="_blank"><br>
                            <img src="https://www.horizonsetfs.com/horizons/media/emails/2020/202002_FieraWebinar/Sentiment-Survey.jpg" alt="Sentiment Survey Results" style="border:none"></a><br>
                            </strong></span><br>
                            <a href="https://www.horizonsetfs.com/sentimentsurvey" target="_blank">Did you miss our Q1 2020 Sentiment Survey Results?</a> See where Canadian advisors and investors stand on 14 different indices and asset classes, ranging from the NASDAQ-100® to Gold Bullion.<br> <p>Stay tuned for our Q2 2020 Sentiment Survey in March – you could win a $150 Amazon gift card!</p>                 
                        </td>
                        <td width="" bgcolor="#EEEEEE">
                            <span class="title"><strong>Just Launched: Three New Total Return ETFs</strong></span><br>
                            <a href="https://www.horizonsetfs.com/news/Press-Release/Horizons-ETFs-Launches-Three-New-Total-Return-ETFs" target="_blank"><br>
                            <img src="https://www.horizonsetfs.com/horizons/media/emails/2020/202002_FieraWebinar/Market-Open-pic.png" alt="Launch of new Total Return ETFs" style="border:none"></a><br>
                            On February 6, 2020, Horizons ETFs launched three new ETFs: <a href="https://www.horizonsetfs.com/etf/hulc">HULC</a>, <a href="https://www.horizonsetfs.com/etf/hsav">HSAV</a>, as well as <a href="https://www.horizonsetfs.com/etf/hxcn">HXCN</a>. With $1 billion in seed capital, HXCN is the largest ETF launch in Canadian history. <a href="https://www.horizonsetfs.com/news/Press-Release/Horizons-ETFs-Launches-Three-New-Total-Return-ETFs" target="_blank">Learn more about our new total return ETFs</a> <br> <br> <br> <br>                       
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>


            <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>                   
                    <td width="30%">
                        <img src="https://www.horizonsetfs.com/horizons/media/emails/2020/202002_FieraWebinar/Nicolas-Normandeau.png" alt="Nicolas Normandeau, CFA®, M.SC." style="border:none"/><span class="orange"><strong>Nicolas Normandeau</strong></span>
                        <br>
                        <strong><span style="font-size: 12px;">CFA®, M.SC. – Vice-President and Portfolio Manager, Fixed Income, Fiera Capital</span></strong>
                    </td>
                    <td width="70%">
                        <em>Nicolas Normandeau is a member of Fiera Capital’s Corporate Fixed Income team and a portfolio manager for the firm’s Corporate Fixed Income strategy with 10 years of industry experience. Fiera Capital is one of Canada’s largest managers of fixed income investments and is the sub-advisor for many of <a href="https://www.horizonsetfs.com/horizons/media/pdfs/library/ActiveIncomeETFs_EN.pdf" target="_blank">Horizons ETFs’ fixed income funds.</a></em>
                    </td>
                    <br>                    
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table> 




          </td>
        </tr>





       <tr> 
          <td width="650"><img src="https://www.horizonsetfs.com/horizons/media/emails/common-images/footer_en.jpg" alt="Horizons Exchange Traded Funds" /></td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
           <td class="disclaimer"><p class="disclaimer1">*Plus  applicable sales taxes.</p>
             <p class="disclaimer1">Commissions, management fees and expenses all  may be associated with an investment in exchange traded products managed by  Horizons ETFs Management (Canada) Inc. (the &quot;Horizons Exchange Traded  Products&quot;). The Horizons Exchange Traded Products are not guaranteed,  their values change frequently and past performance may not be repeated. The  prospectus contains important detailed information about the Horizons Exchange  Traded Products. <strong>Please read the  relevant prospectus before investing.</strong></p>
             <p class="disclaimer1">Certain statements may constitute a forward looking statement, including those identified by the expressions &ldquo;anticipate&rdquo;, &ldquo;estimate&rdquo; or &ldquo;expect&rdquo; and similar expressions (including grammatical variations thereof) to the extent they relate to the ETFs or Horizons ETFs. The forward-looking statements are not historical facts but reflect the ETFs, the ETF&rsquo;s managers or Horizons ETFs current expectations regarding future results or events. These forward-looking statements are subject to a number of risks and uncertainties that could cause actual results or events to differ materially from current expectations. These and other factors should be considered carefully and readers should not place undue reliance on the ETFs&rsquo; forward looking statements. These forward-looking statements are made as of the date hereof and the ETFs do not undertake to update any forward-looking statement that is contained herein, whether as a result of new information, future events or otherwise, unless required by applicable law.</p>
             <p class="disclaimer1"><sup>1</sup>Horizons Total Return ETFs  (&ldquo;Horizons Total Return ETFs&rdquo;) are generally index-tracking ETFs that use an  innovative investment structure known as a Total Return Swap to deliver the  returns of an underlying benchmark in a low-cost and tax-efficient manner.  Unlike a physical replication ETF that typically purchases the securities found  in the relevant benchmark in the same proportions as the benchmark, most  Horizons Total Return ETFs use a synthetic structure that never buys the  securities of a benchmark directly. Instead, the ETF receives the total return  of the benchmark through entering into a Total Return Swap agreement with one  or more counterparties, typically large financial institutions, which will  provide the ETF with the total return of the benchmark in exchange for the  interest earned on the cash held by the ETF. Any distributions which are paid  by the benchmark&rsquo;s constituents are reflected automatically in the net asset  value (NAV) of the ETF. As a result, the Horizons Total Return ETF receives the  total return of the benchmark (before fees), which is reflected in the ETF&rsquo;s  share price, and investors are not expected to receive any taxable  distributions. Certain Horizons Total Return ETFs use physical replication  instead of a total return swap, which includes HULC and HSAV. The Horizons Cash  Maximizer ETF does not track a traditional benchmark but rather a compounding  rate of interest paid on a cash deposit that can change over time.</p>
             <p class="disclaimer1">In the past you have provided Horizons ETFs with your email address or your email address is publicly available. You will receive brief news announcements regarding our ETFs and related topics. If you no longer wish to receive these announcements, you may unsubscribe by <a href="%%email_preference_center%%" target="_blank">clicking here</a> and updating your user preferences.</p>
             <p class="disclaimer1"><a href="http://www.horizonsetfs.com/legal/Privacy-of-information" target="_blank">Click here to read our Privacy Policy.</a></p>
             <p class="disclaimer1">Horizons ETFs Management (Canada) Inc.<br />
55 University Avenue, Suite 800<br />
Toronto, Ontario, M5J 2H7</p></td>
        </tr>
  </table></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Header and footer images are not being reduced at all, they are correctly displaying at 650px width.
The horizontal padding on the `<td>` containing the nested tables is causing your main table to shift from `650px` to `690px` (650 + 20 + 20 = 690), and so causing the images not filling the main table's width.

Changing this line

```
<td align="left" style="padding: 15px 20px 20px 20px;">
```

To, for example

```
<td align="left" style="padding: 15px 0 20px 0;">
```

Solves the issue

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for that Facundo!

Only problem with that approach is that that it strips out the padding on the entire body copy (which is fairly easily added back via a class)

Is there another way to achieve this result?